# Highlight all cells in a given range which are not referenced by a formula (in Excel )

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a excel sheet with I use as a sort of expense log

It is structured as follows:

A1 to A4 -> Some numeric values

A5-> =SUM(A1:A4)

A6 to A10 ->Some numeric values

A11 -> SUM(A5:A10)

So, I essentially keep a sort of checkpoint after every few rows

Now, I have 200+ rows and want to check if I missed out on any of the rows when applying the formulae

Is there an easy way to just select the entire range and tell excel to highlight the cells which are not referenced by a formula?

(trace precedents is a way, but it doesnt make it easy to read and some of the cell depend on numbers outside this range so it goes branching off there as well)

Comment: Would require VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question 100%.
But this macro will highlight all cells who are using a formula

- Open a copy of your excel sheet containing all the data
- press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- open sheet1 from the left pane and insert the code below

  ```
  Sub highlight()
    For Each mycell In UsedRange
      If mycell.HasFormula Then mycell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Next mycell
  End Sub
  ```
- go back to your sheet and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> and execute your macro

Answer (score 0):

A solution today (2020) that would work is:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A200)-2*SUM(IF(ISERROR(FORMULATEXT(A1:A200)),0,A1:A200))<>0,"Uh oh…","All good")
```

(I never liked the TYPE() function because its evil self would not tell me if a formula was in a cell.) However, one might figure to use the above logic and TYPE() to find the cells withOUT formulas and do the same type of calculation. However, TYPE(A1:A200) simply returns "64" telling you the range between its ears (the "()") is... a range (an array, same thing). So it doesn't do the trick, hence the approach above.

When the question was posted one could have used the Excel 4 macros function GET() to return the formula, and tested from that return. But we have FORMULATEXT() now which neatly distinguishes without manipulation as it returns an error for not having a formula in a cell.

All that said, basically, it sums the entire column of data including the subtotals, so that part yields a value two times the value of the data without the subtotals. If you find the cells that are formulas (the subtotals) and SUM() them, AND if you have not missed any data cells when doing each subtotal, the that sum will be half the total of the whole column. So we multiply it by two and subtract it from the simple sum of the whole column.

If the result is 0, all is probably good ("probably" because a weird coincidence (a "perfect storm" if you will) could happen that misleads you). Since it is pretty certain that won't happen if 200 or more cells are involved, it seems a good algorithm. But you should be aware, it's possible that something weird could occur. If the result is not 0, well, it's definite that something was missed in the subtotals, or a cell was included in two subtotals, and given the construction, a whole subtotal would likely be one of those added in twice.